# How to add 2 columns to existing query result based on another query?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, join, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
   field1 as field1 , 
   field2 as field2 , 
   (select count(*) from ... where ...=field1) as field3
FROM
 ...
```

And it works fine - and I see 3 columns in results

The I need to add one more column for internal query:

```
SELECT 
       field1 as field1 , 
       field2 as field2 , 
       (select count(*) as my_count, sum(*) as my _sum from ...where ...=field1 ) as field3
    FROM
     ...
```

this syntax doesn't work.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: oracle or postgres? Please tag only the one database that you are running.

Comment: @GMB, it should work in both of them. it requirement of our application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would seem to do what you want, and it should work fine in Oracle 9i:

```
SELECT t.field1, 
       t.field2,
       x.my_count,
       x.my_sum
  FROM SOME_TABLE t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select FIELD1,
                          count(*) as my_count,
                          sum(SOME_FIELD) as my_sum
                     from SOME_OTHER_TABLE
                     GROUP BY FIELD1) x
    ON x.FIELD1 = t.FIELD1
```

Answer (score 3):

This partial query makes it unsure what you really want, but I would expect that the subquery actually *correlates* to the outer query (otherwise, you could just `cross join`). If so, a typical solution is a lateral join.

In Postgres:

```
select 
   field1 as field1, 
   field2 as field2, 
   x.*
from ...
left join lateral (
     select count(*) as my_count, sum(*) as my _sum from ... 
) x
```

Oracle supports lateral joins starting version 12. You just need to replace `left join lateral` with `outer apply`.

Comment: is there any ANSI compatible solution ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: the `lateral join` is ANSI SQL. But, as you may be aware, databases widely vary in their implementations of the standard. The lateral join syntax for Oracle and Postgres is not that same, that's just how it is...

Comment: @gstackoverflow . . . This IS ANSI-compatible.  Lateral joins are standard SQL.

Comment: hm we use oracle 9 (. I just want to write the same SQL for both databases if it is possible

Comment: My Oracle version is 9. Is there any solution for that version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to precompute the values:

```
WITH
q as (select count(*) as my_count, sum(*) as my _sum from ... )
SELECT 
       field1 as field1 , 
       field2 as field2 , 
       q.my_count as field3, 
       q.my_sum as field4
FROM
...
CROSS JOIN q
```

Or... you can always use the less performant, simpler way:

```
SELECT 
       field1 as field1 , 
       field2 as field2 , 
       (select count(*) from ... ) as field3,
       (select sum(*) from ... ) as field4
    FROM
     ...
```

Comment: what about 

SELECT 
   field1 as field1 , 
   field2 as field2 
FROM ...
CROSS JOIN (select count(*) as my_count, sum(*) as my _sum from ... )

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yep, that works well too. But it needs to have a name (`q` for example).

Comment: oh sorry... the problem here that `(select count(*) as my_count, sum(*) as my _sum from ... ) as field3` references` field1` in where clause....so it doesn't work

Comment: @gstackoverflow Then those values result from a "correlated subquery". You can use the second option in this answer, or a "lateral" query included in a different answer.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Correlated subqueries are expensive. How many rows are you retrieving?

Answer (score 0):

With your limited (& a bit confusing - 2 databases, sum(*) ...) info,

here is the logic:

```
SELECT 
       field1 as field1 , 
       field2 as field2 , 
       (select count(*) from ... ) as my_count,
       (Select sum(<my field>) from ...) as my _sum 
    FROM
     ...
```

Comment: yes, now it works in that way but it looks like query executes twice and it is not optimal

Comment: You have to give, the database, and all table names etc for me to provide with the optimum query

Comment: that info is not enough